# Fixed-point property and $T_0$ separation property

Tags: gn.general-topology, constructive-mathematics, intuitionism

Each topological space $A$ with fixed-point property is $T_0$ space. Proof: suppose, two different points $a_1$ and $a_2$ belong to the same open subsets of $A$. Then the function
$$f(a)=
\begin{cases}
a_1 \quad if\,\, a=a_2\\
a_2 \quad if\,\,a\neq a_2
\end{cases}
$$
is a continuous function without fixed points. Is there an intuitionistic analogue of this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider in intuitionistic mathematics the example of $A$ being the unit interval $[0,1]$ with the trivial topology $\{\emptyset,[0,1]\}$.

Then $A$ is not $T_0$ and yet $A$ still has the fixed-point property since any real function has to be continuous in the usual topology. The fixed-point property here should be read intuitionistically, that is: for a continuous function $f$ it is impossible that $f(x)\# x$ for all $x\in A$.

So I doubt there is a good intuitionistic analogue. The moral here is that intuitionistic spaces have a natural topology (the apartness topology, which for Polish spaces coincides with the metric topology) which cannot be circumvented. This natural topology however is always $T_1$...so there is no big need for an intuitionistic analogue of the above statement.

There is more on intuitionistic separation properties $T_0$-$T_4$ in my PhD thesis [modern intuitionistic topology](https://www.fwaaldijk.nl/modern%20intuitionistic%20topology.pdf).

[with thanks to George Cherevichenko for pointing out the glaring error in my first mistaken answer]

Comment: Can you invert the theorem to "if every space with fixed-point property is $T_0$ then some constructive taboo holds"?

Comment: that's a creative question, i like it :-) but i have no ready answer. if something occurs to me i'll add a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't agree with moral. There are Scott domens, they are interesting, but not $T_1$.

Comment: @GeorgeCherevichenko: If I am allowed to moralize a bit further: the Scott domains, and more generally various posets with $T_0$ topology that is not $T_1$, cannot be easily ignored because they seem to be the only kind of spaces that have the fixed-point property constructively. Even the closed interval $[0,1]$ does not have the fixed-point property constructively. (Frank weaseled out by using a weaker version using apartness!)

Comment: I think, every intuitionistic set must have a "natural preorder" (corresponding to specialization preorder), but I don't know how to define it.

Comment: @AndrejBauer nicely put :-) ! but i need a lot more time to consider how these Scott domains (can) arise intuitionistically, and what the relation to George's question would be. certainly interesting, and i'm again happily surprised by how little i know, and how much there still is to discover/clarify/ameliorate :-)

Comment: @GeorgeCherevichenko another such question which i really need to study... :-)

Comment: The idea that "every set has a topology" begets the topic of [*synthetic topology*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/synthetic+topology). It exists already.